# Integer Manipulation of arrays python

Tags: python, list-manipulation

I have 2 arrays and I need to switch the last digit of the integers in one array with the integers in another. Its better if I show you the output to get a better understanding of what I'm trying to do. I'm not sure this is even possible to do at the least.

Output of arrays:

```
first_array=['3', '4', '5', '2', '0', '0', '1', '7']
second_array=['527', '61', '397', '100', '97', '18', '45', '1']
```

What it then look like:

```
first_array=['3', '4', '5', '2', '0', '0', '1', '7']
second_array =['523', '64', '395', '102', '90', '10', '41', '7']
```

Comment: You array contains strings, not integers. However, in this case it actually makes things easier.

Comment: what their strings ok thanks for the info can i somehow convert them to integers i know its a way in java but not sure in python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> [s[:-1]+f for (f,s) in zip(first_array, second_array)]
['523', '64', '395', '102', '90', '10', '41', '7']
```

Comment: can i somehow convert them to integers i know its a way in java but not sure in python

Comment: @CalvinJones: In Python, at least, it's easier to do with strings. If you want a list of integers as the final result just use `[int(s[:-1]+f) for (f,s) in zip(first_array, second_array)]`

Answer (score 1):

If it is actual integers, you could try "rounding down" each element of the second list to nearest multiple of 10, then adding each element from the first list. For example:

```
>>> first = [3,4,5,6]
>>> second = [235,123,789,9021]
>>> second = [x - (x%10) for x in second]   
>>> second
[230, 120, 780, 9020]
>>> [x + y for (x,y) in zip(first, second)]
[233, 124, 785, 9026]
```